# Postgres to fetch the list having comma separated values

Tags: postgresql, string-aggregation

I am working on Postgres SQL and having below join query, when I execute this query I get two or 3 records for each employee, because each employee has 3 different types of email address 1) Home Address 2) Office address 3) social address.

```
select * from root.employee c
full outer join root.employee_email ce
on c.employee_id = ce.employee_id
order by c.employee_id limit 1000 offset 0;
```

What I want is that `employee_email.email` column to give the comma separated value in the output, how can we do that ?

Note: I've almost 1 million records in DB and will use Spring Batch to migrate data from Postgres to MongoDB. The same I would need to do for Phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate by employee and use `string_agg`:

```
select
    c.employee_id,         -- or just c.* assuming employee_id is a PK
    string_agg(ce.email, ',') as emails
from root.employee c
full outer join root.employee_email ce
    on c.employee_id = ce.employee_id
group by
    c.employee_id
order by
    c.employee_id
limit 1000
offset 0;
```

Comment: What would I need to do get all fields from  both the tables ?

Comment: Is `employee.employee_id` the primary key column?

Comment: Right, but I need all the field to be get mapped it from result set and creat object in Spring Batch

Comment: Yes, `employee.employee_id` is Primary Key column and its UUID

Comment: @JeffCook Then you should be able to select all columns in the `employee` table, q.v. the updated answer.  As for the other table, we would have to aggregate its columns in some way.

Comment: Is there any way to get fields from both the tables please ?

Comment: Your question does not make sense the way you think it does.  For each employee record, there are now _multiple_ records from the other table.  You would need to somehow aggregate those records, we cannot simply "get" them.