# Postgres to bring list all of table fields for particular Employee row?

Tags: postgresql

Taking a reference from link: [Postgres to fetch the list having comma separated values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61848881/postgres-to-fetch-the-list-having-comma-separated-values/61848924?noredirect=1#), I want to write a query which somhow brings Employee email Table fields as a list for a particular Empployee. This is needed for Spring Batch to Simply match it from the Resultset and create a POJO/Model class like List emails for Employee class?

Can this be possible ?

```
select c.*, ce.*, string_agg(ce.email, ',') as emails
from root.employee c
full outer join root.employee_email ce
    on c.employee_id = ce.employee_id
group by
    c.employee_id, ce.employee_email_id
order by
    c.employee_id
limit 1000
offset 0;
```

Comment: What exactly is the output you are looking for?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I need Employee Row and list of Emails should embedded in it.

Comment: But isn't that what this query does?

Comment: Right, it does, but at String Batch its overridig all with the last record :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is a common one in the batch processing realm and with Spring Batch it is called "Driving Query Based ItemReaders", you can find more about that in [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/common-patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders).

Basically you retrieve the Contacts in your reader, and in your processor you add the list of Emails to them.

```
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "")
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<Employee> employeeReader(DataSource dataSource) {
        JdbcCursorItemReader<Employee> ItemReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
        ItemReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        ItemReader.setSql("SELECT * FROM employee.employee C ");
        ItemReader.setRowMapper(new EmployeeRowMapper());
        return ItemReader;
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<Employee, Employee> settlementHeaderProcessor(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate){

        return item -> {
      root.EMPLOYEE_EMAIL CE WHERE ce.employee_id = ? ",
                    new Object[]{item.getId()},
                    new RowMapper<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public String mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
                            return resultSet.getString("EMAIL");
                        }
                    });

            item.setEmails(emails);

            return item;
        };
    }
```

**PS** : this could have some performance issues if you have lots of contacts, because for each contact Item you will hit the database to retrieve Emails.

There is another optimized way, by creating a custom reader that will return a **List** of Contacts (For example 1000 by 1000), and a processor that will enrich them with their emails. This way you will hit the database again for each 1000 Contact Item.

In your reader your retrieve a list of unique Employees page per page (Say your page is 1000 long).
And in your processor for the 1000 employees you retrieve all their emails in one query.

Then for each employee you set the emails retrieved in the last query.

An example might like the following:

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Employee, Integer> {
}

@Getter
class EmployeeVO {
    private Long employeeId;
    private String email;

    EmployeeVO(Long employeeId, String email) {
        this.employeeId= employeeId;
        this.email = email;
    }
}

public class EmployeeListReader implements ItemReader<List<Employee>> {

    private final static int PAGE_SIZE = 1000;

    private final EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    private int page = 0;

    public EmployeeListReader(EmployeeRepository employeeRepository) {
        this.employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
    }


    public List<Employee> read() throws Exception {
        Page<Employee> employees = employeeRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(page, PAGE_SIZE));
        page++;

        return employees.getContent();
    }
}

@Bean 
EmployeeListReader reader(){
    return new EmployeeListReader(this.employeeRepository);
}

@Bean
public ItemProcessor<List<Employee>, List<Employee>> settlementHeaderProcessor(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate) {

    return item -> {

        List<Long> employeesIds = item.stream().map(Employee::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());

        SqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource("ids", employeesIds);

        List<ContactVO> emails = namedParameterJdbcTemplate
                                    .query("SELECT CE.employeeId, CE.EMAIL FROM employee_EMAIL CE WHERE ce.contact_id IN  (:ids) ",
                parameters,
                new RowMapper<ContactVO>() {
                    @Override
                    public ContactVO mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
                        return new ContactVO(
                                resultSet.getLong("EMPLOYEE_ID"),
                                resultSet.getString("EMAIL"));
                    }
                });

        Map<Long, List<ContactVO>> emailsByContactId = emails.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ContactVO::getContactId));

        List<Employee> newEmployeesWithEmails = Collections.unmodifiableList(item);

        newEmployeesWithEmails.forEach(employee -> {
            employee.setEmails(emailsByContactId.get(employee.getId()).stream().map(ContactVO::getEmail).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        });

        return newEmployeesWithEmails;
    };
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Agree ! Thanks for details. Yes, making a DB call from Processor is devil since I've 1 million records, Do you've sample example to create custom Reader /.

Comment: You are welcome. Sure, I have added an example of the Reader and Processor.

Comment: Hey Thanks, I 'm not using JPA/Hibernate here, I would need to get this data using Spring JDBC, I still think issue remain there, because I would get 3 row for Employee having 3 different emails and then I would need to create single Employee and embed 3 emails inside employee

Comment: Corrected column names, Employee & Email both are different tables, Email table has 3 different email object for single Employee, so employee object is same, but 3 different email object. Can you please delete `owner` name pls ?

Comment: Sure, done. I think the second solution responds to your need, I have added more details , please check it.

Comment: Hey Thanks, for now for Employee, I would need to bring Email object, Phone, Department object and embdded into Employee collection in Mongo. Since using JdbcTemplate I would need to get 1000 records first then for each Employee I would need to call Email table, Phone table and department table, this would table so much time to pull data

Comment: No, you shouldn't hit the database for each Employee. You can either use NamedParameterJdbcTemplate, or if you can only use JdbcTemplate construct your Query String that contains IN clause of 1000 Employee Ids.  This way for each 1000 employee you hit the database only one time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214112/discussion-between-jeff-cook-and-youness-bout).