# Postgres Rederive the column

Tags: postgresql

I'm taking an reference from the link : [Postgres to fetch the list having comma separated values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61848881/postgres-to-fetch-the-list-having-comma-separated-values). just wanted to see if we can modify below query, if Employee has more than 1 email Id present, then 1 else 0. I want to have these 0 & 1 value into separatw column,

Can we do this ?

```
select c.*,
    string_agg(ce.email, ',') as emails
from root.employee c
full outer join root.employee_email ce
    on c.employee_id = ce.employee_id
group by
    c.employee_id
order by
    c.employee_id
limit 1000
offset 0;
```

Comment: You can add a `boolean` expression quite easily: `count(ce.email) > 1 as multiple_emails`

Comment: Thanks, what I would need to change when I want all columns from the email table as well? How would I get only those columns where multiple_emails is true?

Comment: What do you mean with "all columns"? Do you want to include all columns of the `contact_email` table in the result? That is a different question, but you could use an aggregate of JSON values.

Comment: I would need all columns from `employee_email` and `employee `